# json.loads throwing error when the JSON is valid

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have json data that you can download from [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/X8f4Nz6v) (its too long to paste here). This data is being read from a file and loaded using `json.loads(str)`. For example:

```
path = open(file_path_presented).read())
try:
    retval = json.load(open(path))
except Exception as e:
    if "File name too long" in str(e):
        retval = json.loads(path)
        # erroring out here with the json in the link
```

Every time I load this json I receive the following error:

```
EXCEPTION INFORMATION: Traceback (most recent call):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/rando/bin/python/mt/api/api_handler.py", line 932, in get
    retval = json.loads(str(path))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 25 (char 24)
```

My best guess is that this error has something to do with the json data having `{` and `}` characters in it that are not being escaped properly because it only happens sometimes and not all the time. I've used multiple linters and all of them say that the JSON is valid JSON, along with `jq`. How can I load this json with throwing an error?

I've tried loading the data as a `StringIO` into `json.load(io)` with:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

io = StringIO(path)
retval = json.load(io)
```

As well as fixing the JSON using a regex, and using `json.loads(path, strict=False)` However these all produce the sane error

Comment: You need to post how you're loading the JSON string into Python, I guess. If your code sample of `json.loads(str(path))` is really trying to load the path, then that would explain the error? In `json.loads`, the last "s" stands for "load string," so you should pass it a string, not a path. `json.load` would take a path.

Comment: I don't seen anything around column 25 that would cause a parse error if that's what `loads` is actually receiving. It's not clear what `fix` is or what it is doing.

Comment: @BenQuigley the data is being loaded from a file hence: `This data is being read from a file and loaded using json.loads(str(path))` the variable "path" isn't relevant in the context as the variable just wasn't changed from the last person who edited the code (there's multiple ways that the data can present itself in a file either a path or raw json string we're dealing with a raw json string in a file)

Comment: @chepner its in the link

Comment: That's the *data*. Is that the content of the variable `path`? If you actually have something like `path = "/path/to/my/data.json"`, then there's your problem: `loads` is trying to parse the *file name* as JSON, not the contents of the file. You want `json.load`, not `json.loads`.

Comment: seems to load fine. [https://onlinegdb.com/Kmh7uEuVW](https://onlinegdb.com/Kmh7uEuVW)

Comment: If I retrieve the data directly from the url using `requests.get(url).json()` I don't get any error. What is `fix` doing?

Comment: @BenQuigley is that better?

Comment: Can you show us what `file_path_presented` is? What it contains?

Comment: @C.Nivs `file_path_presented` will contain either a path to a file in the database, or raw json data. So if "File name too long" is in the error we assume it's raw JSON data and try to load it using `json.loads` otherwise we load it as a filename itself with `json.load`

Comment: @C.Nivs fix was a typo

Comment: why don't you test `file_path_presented[0] in ('{', '[')`. if True use `loads(file_path...`, if False then `with open(...` and pass the file object to `load(file_obj)`.

Comment: Why are you calling `open` twice? `json.load(open(file_path_presented))` or `json.loads(path)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the JSON data.

You may not be using the most appropriate technique for converting it to a Python dictionary.

Consider this:

```
import requests
import json

TARGET = '/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.json'
with requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/X8f4Nz6v', stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    with open(TARGET, 'wb') as j:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(4096):
            j.write(chunk)
with open(TARGET) as j:
    d = json.load(j)
```

This code runs to completion without any exception(s)

**Optionally:**

If you don't want to create a local file you can just build a bytearray as follows:

```
with requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/X8f4Nz6v', stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    b = bytearray()
    for chunk in r.iter_content(4096):
        b += chunk
    d = json.loads(b.decode())
```

Comment: The issue was that the raw json string in the file was being cut off while reading it. However, your answer is the most logical one so I'm accepting it. Thank you